# QPushButton не правильно зуммируется в QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

Добавил QPushButton в QGraphicsScene, но когда я пытаюсь зуммировать сцену форма кнопки смещается. На фото кнопки до зума и после.[image: так кнопки выглядят после после зума сцены]

[image: Так кнопки выглядят до зума]

Comment: А должны менять размер? У них он вроде фиксировано задаётся, если только отдельно их не настраивать, типа в лайаут какой-то класть или политики там какие-то задавать. И откуда скриншоты? Когда я последний раз работал с Qt там не было такого в дизайнере форм

Comment: Это не в дизайнере сделано. Я использовал графику Qt (QGraphicsScene и QGraphicsView)

Comment: Ок. Но понятнее в чем проблема не стало. "когда я пытаюсь зуммировать сцену форма кнопки смещается" - а почему она не должна смещаться? Там прописано где-то что размер кнопки привязан к масштабу сцены?(QPushButton это же просто кнопка с фиксированым размером, если она не в Layout) Пример бы коротенький, я бы тогда хоть документацию почитал. А так пока выглядит что QPushButton ничего не знает про то что вы меняете маштаб сцены, и просто остаётся в старых размерах.

Comment: Я проверил этот же код в Windows 10 и там такой проблемы нет. Похоже это баг на Mac OS